# Qual a diferença entre utilizar getBoundingClientRect() e Intersection Observer para verificar se o elemento esta visivel na tela

Tags: javascript

Normalmente eu utilizo este modo para verificar se o elemento esta realmente visivel na tela, pois tenho um pouco mais de flexibilidade. Existe alguma diferença grande entre este modo e Intersection Observer?

```js
if (ev.getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight && ev.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embora possa usar pra observar algumas informações sobre uma área retangular, eles são bem diferentes

Seguindo a documentação do `getBoundingClientRect()` aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

> O método Element.getBoundingClientRect() retorna o tamanho de um
> elemento e sua posição relativa ao viewport.
> O valor de retorno é o objeto DOMRect que é a uniāo dos retângulos
> retornados por getClientRects() para o elemento, ou seja, os atributos
> border-boxes do CSS associados ao elemento.
>
> O valor retornado é um objeto DOMRect, que contém as propriedades
> apenas-leitura left, top, right e bottom que descrevem o border-box em
> pixels. top e left são relativos às propriedades top-left do viewport.

Ou seja, retorna um elemento.

Já a documentação do `IntersectionObserver()` aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport.

Em tradução livre:

> A API Intersection Observer fornece uma maneira de observar de forma
> assíncrona as alterações na interseção de um elemento de destino com
> um elemento ancestral ou com a janela de visualização de um documento
> de nível superior.

Retorna também um elemento mas ligeiramente diferente do `getBoundingClientRect()`, como pode ser visto também na documentação:

> **The intersection root and root margin** Before we can track the intersection of an element with a container, we need to know what that
> container is. That container is the intersection root, or root
> element. This can be either a specific element in the document which
> is an ancestor of the element to be observed, or null to use the
> document's viewport as the container.
>
> The root intersection rectangle is the rectangle used to check against
> the target or targets. This rectangle is determined like this:
>
> - If the intersection root is the implicit root (that is, the top-level Document), the root intersection rectangle is the viewport's
>   rectangle.
> - If the intersection root has an overflow clip, the root intersection rectangle is the root element's content area.
> - Otherwise, the root intersection rectangle is the intersection root's bounding client rectangle (as returned by calling
>   getBoundingClientRect() on it).

Em tradução livre:

> **A raiz da intersecção e a margem da raiz** Antes de rastrearmos a interseção de um elemento com um contêiner, precisamos saber o que é
> esse contêiner. Esse contêiner é a raiz da interseção , ou elemento
> raiz . Pode ser um elemento específico no documento, que é um
> ancestral do elemento a ser observado, ou nullusar a janela de
> visualização do documento como o contêiner.
>
> O retângulo de interseção raiz é o retângulo usado para verificar o
> alvo ou alvos. Este retângulo é determinado assim:
>
> - Se a raiz de interseção for a raiz implícita (ou seja, o nível superior Document), o retângulo de interseção da raiz é o retângulo da
>   janela de visualização.
> - Se a raiz de interseção tiver um clipe de estouro, o retângulo de interseção da raiz será a área de conteúdo do elemento raiz.
> - Caso contrário, o retângulo de interseção da raiz é o retângulo cliente delimitador da raiz da interseção (conforme retornado ao chamar
>   getBoundingClientRect()).

Ou seja:

- `IntersectionObserver()` pode retornar um elemento similar ao `getBoundingClientRect()` ou não, dependendo da forma que o elemento é "calculado" na interseção.
- enquanto `getBoundingClientRect()` retorna um elemento, `IntersectionObserver()` permite usar um *callback*, passando para outra função avaliar as mudanças ocorridas. Ou seja, a função precisa chamar o `getBoundingClientRect()` para obter o elemento e avaliar suas propriedades, como `top`, já `IntersectionObserver()` pode criar um *callback*, se será "automaticamente" chamado quando houver mudanças.

Comment: Show Brother, Otimo como sempre nas respostas. Vou manter o mouse precionada nessa resposta.